# Function Output in Different Cell

Tags: excel, function, vba

I'm trying to write a function in one cell, and then using that cell's address as a reference point, I'd like to change the value of a cell on Sheet2.  Essentially, I'm attempting to make a function yield two different outputs, each output on a different sheet.  Here's what I have so far:

```
Function test() As Variant
    Application.Caller.Worksheet.Cells(Application.Caller.Row,Application.Caller.Column).Row
    Application.Caller.Worksheet.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, Application.Caller.Column).Column
    Sheet2.Cells(a + 1, b + 1).Value = 8
End Function
```

The goal with this is to type "=TEST()" in cell A1 on Sheet1, and A1 would equal zero while cell B2 on Sheet2 would equal 8.  I've heard rumors that Excel simply won't allow a UDF to affect change to any other cell other than the one in which it was written, but I really don't want to believe that rumor!

Comment: @pnuts, lots of good info. Thanks for the link. I'll see if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with a combination of a function **(UDF)** and an **Event Macro.**

The UDF would place a value in **A1** and the event macro would detect this occurrence and change the cell on the other sheet.

Comment: I haven't used an event macro before, but after reading about it, it sounds like it might do the trick! I'll try it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: You will need the **Calculate** event macro!

Comment: It's a bummer that Excel won't allow all this to be done in a UDF, but at least there's a fantastic work-around. Thanks for helping me!